# Does conditional operator in cpp evaluate both operands?

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators, conditional-operator

https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways/

my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numDecodings(string s) {
        vector<int> dp(s.size(),0);
        
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            int x =0;
            if(s[i]-'0'>0 && s[i]-'0'<=9)
            {
                x = (i>0)? dp[i-1]:1;
            } 
            if(i!=0 && stoi(s.substr(i-1,2))<=26)
            {
                cout<<i<<" ";
                x = x + (i>=2 )? dp[i-2]:1;
            }    
            dp[i] =x;
        }
        return dp[s.size()-1];
       
    }
};
```

Running this code gives this error

```
Line 924: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000010 overflowed to 0x60200000000c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:34
```

My question is does the conditional operator evaluate dp[i-2] in **(i>=2 )? dp[i-2]:1;** even if the condition doesn't satisfy? Replacing it with a normal if-else solved my problem.

Comment: I suggest you try to create a [mcve] using the code you show, then you can easily use a debugger to step through the code and see any problems yourself. To help you with this I also suggest you simplify complex expression so you can see the intermediate values used in the complex expressions, as well as use `if-else` instead of the conditional expression.

Comment: Well, no.   `condition ? true_result() : false_result()` only ever evaluates one of `true_result()` or `false_result()`.     But your problem is misunderstanding of operator precedence   `x = x + (i >= 2) ? dp[i-2] : 1` which is equivalent to `x = (x + (i >= 2)) ? dp[i-2] : 1` - note the additional pair of `()`.    If `x` is initially non-zero, then `dp[i-2]` can be evaluated for `i < 2` which is clearly not what you expect - and will give undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
x = x + (i>=2) ? dp[i-2] : 1;
```

is likely not doing what you intend. The ternary `?:` has lower precedence than `+`, so the statement actually becomes:

```
x = (x + (i>=2)) ? dp[i-2] : 1;
```

which means you are checking the `true`ness of `x + (i>=2)` instead of just `i>=2`. This is why `dp[i-2]` can be evaluated even when `i < 2`, because the entire expression `x + (i>=2)` could still be true.

You can fix this by putting explicit parentheses yourself:

```
x = x + ((i>=2) ? dp[i-2] : 1);
```

or rewriting it like this:

```
x += i>=2 ? dp[i-2] : 1;
```

Comment: The condition would also evaluate to true for values of `x` less than `-1`.   Although, admittedly, the OP's code will never have `x` negative.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't evaluate the way you think it does.
`x = x + (i>=2 )? dp[i-2]:1;`

Per [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the addition operator has a higher precedence than the ternary operator. Placing the ternary expression in parentheses should provide the desired behavior.

`x += ((i>=2 ) ? dp[i-2] : 1);` gets the job done. Even though I changed the operator to remove the redundant `x`, the parentheses are still necessary.

Comment: Removing the additional parentheses in `x += ((i>=2 ) ? dp[i-2] : 1);` did not cause any problem. The code worked fine.

Comment: Good to know. I've had plenty of times where they were still necessary. I suppose I used them because in my head I still treat the ternary operator as two operators.